# Retrieving the return value from Oracle with C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I'd like to be able to retrieve the return value from a function in Oracle with c#.
Currently, this is what  I have:

For SQL:

```
 FUNCTION add_resource (
     project_view BOOLEAN,
     project_id NUMBER,
     worker_id  NUMBER,
     role_id    NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
     resource_id NUMBER;
 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO RESOURCE_T (WORKERID, ROLEID, PROJECTID)
   VALUES (worker_id, role_id, project_id)
   RETURNING RESOURCEID INTO resource_id;
   RETURN resource_id;
 END add_resource;
```

For C#

```
cmdText = "DECLARE resource_id NUMBER; BEGIN resource_id := PKG_RAP.add_resource(" + projectView + "," + id + "," + record["WORKERID"] + "," + record["ROLEID"] + "); END;"; 

using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdText, conn))
    {
         OracleTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
         try
         {
          OracleParameter prm = new OracleParameter("resource_id", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
          cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);                      
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          trans.Commit();
         }catch 
         {
          trans.Rollback();
          throw;
         }
    }
```

The query works individually when I test it out in the database, however, the c# is not able to grab the value for resource_id and only gets "null". Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this not work?

```
cmdText = @"select PKG_RAP.add_resource(:projectView, :projectId, :workerId, :roleId) from dual";
using (var cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdText, conn))
using (cmd.Parameters.Add(":projectView", projectView))
using (cmd.Parameters.Add(":projectId", id))
using (cmd.Parameters.Add(":workerId", record["WORKERID"]))
using (cmd.Parameters.Add(":roleId", record["ROLEID"]))
using (var tx = conn.BeginTransaction()) {
    try {
        // resource ID
        var resourceId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        tx.Commit();
        return resourceId;
    } catch {
        tx.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
}
```

This seems (to me) like the simplest solution to calling a PL-SQL function to return a single value.

ETA: I don't have sufficient rep to comment, yet, but Marc, above, means that you don't return anything in the PL-SQL block you are executing.

Comment: Your code did not work out for me, however your edit about Marc's comment helped me out. Thanks!

Comment: I can see I missed calling tx.Commit(), and misspelled ROLEID on one of the parameters. Did this fail in any particular way?

Comment: It gave me this error:
ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number.
I wonder why Marc deleted his answer

Comment: Ah. I missed a parameter.

Comment: Yup. However, it still gave me the error earlier though even after I corrected it.

Comment: According my knowledge boolean values are not supported in SQL (only inside PL/SQL). Check the solution carefully regarding the boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

The command text must be like this one if you like to call a function (and if you want or have to avoid `select ... from dual`:

```
cmdText = "BEGIN :resource_id := PKG_RAP.add_resource(" + projectView + "," + id + "," + record["WORKERID"] + "," + record["ROLEID"] + "); END;";
```

As John Pederson already answered, all parameters should be defined as bind values, e.i.

```
cmdText = "BEGIN :resource_id := PKG_RAP.add_resource(:projectView, :projectId, :workerId, :roleId); END;";
```

However, I don't think you can use boolean variables when calling from C#. You have to cast it, e.g. to "0" and "1"

Comment: Well, I am using PL/SQL and got it to work. I found that my mistake was indeed the bind variables which marc (another answerer) pointed out earlier.
So your first line of code is exactly what mine ended up looking like and it worked :)
That is also after I changed the parameter direction to output